# Solve simultaneous differential equations with imbedded functions and a parameter estimation

Tags: matlab, differential-equations

The aim is to solve the below equations and plot m with time, i.e. dm/dt

k is unknown and needs to be estimated. For the parameter estimation, the below values for m versus t can be used. This is a dummy dataset, as I would like to get an idea if this problem is solvable. If needed, an initial guesstimate for k can be provided 6e-5 m2/bar.hr.

I have added an initial idea for the code, but not sure if my implementation of the A(H) and P(H) functions in the odes is correct. Also I need a way to estimate for k whilst fitting to the provided m vs t data.

[image]
[image]

```
function dydt = diffunTAR(~,y,k, h, A_H, P_H, rho_h, rho_o, wo)
dydt = zeros (2,1);
D = 2.64/1000 %mm/1000 to convert to m
r=D/2
rho_o = 1320 %kg/m3
rho_h = 1000 % kg/m3
wo=648/1000000 %weight component 1 in mg converted to kg
h= 1.5/1000 %1.5mm expressed in m
        function A_H= pi*(D/2)^2 + (2/r)*(1+(rho_o/rho_h*y(2)))*(wo/rho_o);
        end
            function P_H = 5004.6*y(2) + 150.39;
            end 
%dV/dt
dydt(1)= (k/h)* function A_H* function P_H;
%dH/dt
dydt(2)= (rho_h*k/wo*h)*function A_H*function P_H;
end

tspan = linspace(0,21*24); %time in hrs for 21 days
y0 = [0 6.4800e-04];
[t,y]=ode45(@(t,y) diffunTAR(t,y, k, h, A_H0, rho_h, rho_o, wo), tspan, y0);
```

**updated code after help**

```
function dydt = diffunTAR(~,y,k,h,rho_h,rho_o,wo,L,r)
dydt = zeros (2,1);
%dV/dt
dydt(1)= k/h* AH * PH;
%dH/dt
dydt(2)= (rho_h*k/wo*h) * AH * PH;          
AH
PH
function PH
    (5004.6*y(2))+150.3;
end
function AH
    pi*(r^2)+(2/r)*(1+(rho_o/rho_h*y(2)))*(wo/rho_o);
    setInitialConditions (AH, 2*pi*(r)*L+2*pi*(r)^2);
end
end
```

```
D = 2.64/1000 %mm/1000 to convert to m
r=D/2
L = 10.6/100 %cm/100 to convert to m
wo=648/1000000 %weight osmotic tablets in mg converted to kg
k=6e-5 %guess for permeability
h= 1.5/1000 %1.5mm expressed in m
rho_o = 1320 %kg/m3
rho_h = 1000 % kg/m3
tspan = linspace(0,21*24); %time in hrs for 21 days
y0 = [0 6.4800e-04];
[t,y]=ode45(@(t,y) diffunTAR(t,y,k,h,rho_h,rho_o,wo,L,r), tspan, y0);
```

Comment: is this a question for [Mathematics.SE] or is there a  coding question in here somewhere? If you can formulate the problem as an ODE then it is solvable.

Comment: It's a coding question, I think the mathematics is straightforward. Maybe I will adapt with some initial thoughts on the code.

Comment: I think this is a question for [Computational Science](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: There are some syntax errors in this code. It can't be run.

Comment: Thanks I added it to the Computational Science forum.

Comment: If I try to run it as it is, I get the following error:  Error: File: diffunTAR.m Line: 9 Column: 25
Invalid use of operator.

Error in FitODETAR_2>@(t,y)diffunTAR(t,y,k,h,A_H0,rho_h,rho_o,wo)

Error in odearguments (line 90)
f0 = feval(ode,t0,y0,args{:});   % ODE15I sets args{1} to yp0.

Error in ode45 (line 115)
  odearguments(FcnHandlesUsed, solver_name, ode, tspan, y0, options, varargin);" I also need a way to do the "k" parameter estimation using the release (m) vs time (t) dataset provided.

Comment: Your function syntax is wrong. See [nested function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/nested-functions.html).

Comment: Thanks I think this solved a lot of problems, updated code in main text. Still an error comes up: Error using diffunTAR/AH
Too many output arguments.

Error in diffunTAR (line 4)
dydt(1)= (k/h)* AH * PH;

Error in FitODETAR_2>@(t,y)diffunTAR(t,y,k,h,rho_h,wo)

Error in odearguments (line 90)
f0 = feval(ode,t0,y0,args{:});   % ODE15I sets args{1} to yp0.

Error in ode45 (line 115)
  odearguments(FcnHandlesUsed, solver_name, ode, tspan, y0, options, varargin);